# SVN Commit and difference between a file and e formatted file

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, version-control, versioning

How do you manage the maintenance/right format of code without problems with merge and difference hystory?

For eg. I have a very old file in repository with a wrong format like:

```
/**
 * Old code
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {System.out.println(i);}
}
```

then i format the code in:

```
/**
 * Formatted code (ctrl-shift-f in Eclipse)
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

If I compare this code with repository, I see a lot of change and I don't see the real difference (I change the limit 10 to 10000).

How do you manage versioning between "format code" and "activity code"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Subversion doesn't understand programming languages or context - it just recognizes that the file changed. When you reformat the code, you'll get lots of minute changes. Your options:

1. Don't ever auto-format your code
2. Always auto-format your code, from the moment you create a new file
3. Deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle something like that you'll need a tool that actually understands the language.  Version control systems don't include such capabilities since they're designed to be generalized and the language doesn't really matter (assuming the language is in text and not binary data).

The only such tool that I'm aware of is [SemanticMerge](http://www.semanticmerge.com/).  Which knows about C# and Java only at this point.  It can be configured with your version control system to replace the built in merging.

One suggestion I'd make is don't mix formatting and functional changes.  If you want to reformat do that in a separate commit from the functional change.  Typically I commit these changes with a note in the commit message saying there is no functional change.  This helps anyone merging it to know that nothing should behave differently with the change and any behavior changing is an error in their merging.